# Click not working in selenium and nightwatch

Tags: jquery, selenium

I have this problem with nightwatch, where .click() is not working with selector. I added the --verbose argument and it displayed this message "**is not clickable at point (525, 560)**". It works with regular jquery execution, but I need it to work on nightWatch commands and selenium.

I created a custom command to click, which includes a verification to see if object is visible before clicking. I am adding this function below, as well as the full error from the --verbose argument.

```
module.exports.command = function(source) {
  let self = this

    self
  .waitForElementVisible(source,6000)

  .click(source)

  return self
}
```

value: { message: 'unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (525, 560). Other element would receive the click: ...\n  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64)' } }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid that error from selenium, you must move or hover the pointer into that position, you can do that with .moveToElement.

You may also see its usage in the documentation [nightwatch-docs](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/extending-nightwatch/custom-commands.md).

Just to clarify this is not really a nightwatch bug but a selenium bug.

```
module.exports.command = function(source) {
  let self = this

    self
  .waitForElementVisible(source,6000)
  .moveToElement(source,undefined, undefined)
  .click(source)

  return self
}
```

Comment: hehehe saved my life that worked like a charm thanks.

Comment: @moplin, what makes you think that it's a Selenium bug and that `.moveToElement` is the solution? It's probably working in this case because of the delay introduced by `.moveToElement`. The Chrome driver usually raise this error when the click is perform during a css transition or when the targeted element is covered by  another one (footer or header).

Comment: @FlorentB. actually after I used mplon solution I found out that the click thing according to nightwatch is a selenium issue, because element is not clickable at that point, but what hovering over does is set it to an over state making it work, at least in my case this solved it because if not, according to verbose the click since the element is not present will be targeted o another element.

Comment: @FlorentB. this is an example of how this issue was adressed by nightwatch, and they even close the issue and reffer it to a selenium only issue https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/1047

Comment: @rafael matovelle, Have you tried with a delay before the click?
 `browser.pause(100);`

Comment: @FlorentB. you may me right its only a delay issue but pause wont do it, and this fix is also failing, working better but still failing

Answer (score 1):

In some cases (especially with Chrome browser) a problem can be caused by other elements overlapping the target one. This can be sometimes mitigated by maximizing the browser window beforehand.

In other words, adding something like `browser.windowMaximize();` before the test can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with chromedriver 2.30 but when updated to 2.33 I was able to click with no workarounds. I see that you already have 2.33.

You may as well update Selenium Server. I am using '3.4.0' and '3.5.0' and it worked with chromedriver 2.33